# iOS - iPhone 5 Can't Scroll to the Bottom of TableView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, iphone-5

I am testing my application on the iPHone 5. I have a UITableView with about 80 entries and it seems to work just fine on the iPhone 5 except that the last 4 entries are past the screen when I hit the bottom. I have to drag the tableview past the end resting position to see these cells, but it bounces back to being cut off when I release it.

I have no issues with the 4S when I run the same build.

How can I fix this?

Thanks!
Alan

Comment: please post some code relevant for showing the cells / tableview.

Comment: Does the code matter if it works flawlessly on the 4S, but not the 5? I am not messing with the frame of the UITableView. It's just created using IB. I am basically filling in the delegate/datasource methods, which should not affect if I can scroll to see the last couple cells? correct me if i'm wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I realized in interface builder that in Autosizing if you have the I bar enabled for the bottom, it will stretch it beyond the view for iPhone 5. It seems that this is the default for tableviews.